# How to accept chat if acceptChat() method isn't supported with Omni-Channel in API version 38

Tags: api, integration, liveagent, developer-console, chat

I need to use this accept function

```
sforce.console.chat.acceptChat(chatKey:String, (optional)callback:Function)
```

in API version 38.0 - but in documentation it says that *acceptChat() isn't supported with Omni-Channel in API version 37.0 or later.* My version is 38. What is the appropriate method to accept chat?

Comment: Can you not simply use a lower version?

Comment: No that is not an option